# How can I achive something similar to Flickr's website?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I would like to know how can I achive something similar to [Flickr's homepage](https://www.flickr.com/)? Im talking about the transparent slides with the static background. So far I know how to use an static background and navigate accross transparent DIVs but I dont know how the slide "system" works.

Thanks.

Comment: You should look up Parralax scrolling, and also scrollTo there are good libraries out there.

Comment: Why would some1 downvote this? @craigie2204 thank! I will definitely give them a try.,

Comment: [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) is your answer. Just use the plugin option `scrollBar:true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by just making an normal website but adding an `auto scroller` script to your page.

The buttons to go down and up are just some `<a href="#id"></a>` tags with an id as link. Normally you would be instant at that id, but with your `auto scroller` you it will go smooth.

Here is an `auto scroller` which I always use for my websites ( [an example by pressing in the menu](http://rekenopjetoekomst.nl/test/test.html) ):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
      $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
          var target = $(this.hash);
          target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
          if (target.length) {
            $('html,body').animate({
              scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 2000 /*<-- This is your time for every scroll in miliseconds*/);
            return false;
          }
        }
      });
    });
    </script>
```

I hope this helped for you.

Comment: That's not the same. Doesn't scroll automatically on scrolling with the mouse.

Comment: You can Just make an script that calls your scroller.. Very easy I think

Comment: Not that easy when you start thinking about kinetic scrolling (apple laptops),  touch devices, performance (which is quite slow with jQuery), responsive design etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would say: use [fullpage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) library.

It will make your live easy and beautiful :)

Just remember to use `scrollBar:true` if you want to show the scrollbar as in Flickr website.